# PyTube denied access to internet in Docker image

Tags: docker, network-programming, pytube

So I converted my project to a docker image so it can be run without having local installations of programs except docker. I used the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/yt-processor
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

It has its own SQLite db, hence the migrate command, but the issue that I am facing is that PyTube can't connect to the internet to download the file. The error is specifically in this command:

```
from pytube import YouTube
...
yt = YouTube(video_url)
```

I tried using `ping google.com` in the image and it returned successful results but somehow this part of the code doesn't want to work. The project works great in my local machine but as soon as I create a docker image and try to execute it there, nothing works. Here's a log of the same command being executed in the docker shell:

```
# python
Python 3.10.13 (main, Nov 29 2023, 05:20:19) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pytube import YouTube
>>> yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=480OGItLZNo")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.prefetch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 181, in prefetch
    self.vid_info_raw = request.get(self.vid_info_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/request.py", line 36, in get
    return _execute_request(url).read().decode("utf-8")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/request.py", line 24, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request)  # nosec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 557, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 749, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 410: Gone
```

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: If you're getting an HTTP error like that, then all of the Docker-level network wiring is fine.  Either you're feeding an invalid URL to YouTube, or it's just decided it doesn't want to answer requests from your library.  `ping` is a very low-level network diagnostic utility that doesn't use the same protocols as HTTP, and it doesn't really demonstrate anything, particularly during the image build.

Comment: Oh I see, well I tried using other YouTube urls, trying age-restricted as well open youtube content, but nothing worked. So I guess it is a pytube problem and not a docker one?